# Sport as a performing art on the report of aesthetic philosophy

Tags: reference-request

I am seeking additional philosophical references.
For instance:

> J. Neville Turner, 1992. ["Is sport an art form?"](http://library.la84.org/SportsLibrary/SportingTraditions/1992/st0802/st0802e.pdf), Sporting Traditions 8, pp. 153–166.

I suppose that both disciplines are fond of harmony as originality,
so they appeal to an educated common sense. Is this what philosophers have said?

Comment: See [The Definition of Art](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/art-definition/#ConDefArt) for difefrent approaches to the very controversial issue regarding the nature and definition of *art*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. The body of your post seems to answer the title question, so what is your question?  "Am I right" and "what do you think" questions are off-topic on this SE.

Comment: Check out the musicologist Hans Keller - he used to write a football column for the Daily Mail (I think it was). He likened football to ballet and took the same pleasure from it.

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. It would be good if you would put the reference into context, explain how it is related and clarify your concrete question.

Comment: Hi @Labory, I changed your question into a reference request and nominated it for reopening.  I recognize that this substantially changes your question, so feel free to revert my edits if you choose.  However, this new version is more likely to be viewed as a valid, on-topic question for our site, the old one has the issues listed above.  BTW, you might enjoy my own essay on the [Aesthetics of Football](https://partiallyexaminedlife.com/2015/06/01/the-aesthetics-of-football/).

Answer (score 1):

This question can be best answered by the motivation of the participant.

Let's say you have a tennis star. He loves tennis; he plays it all the time. The fact that he's so good at it that he gets paid to do it full time is a side point.

This man is a hobbyist. Tennis is his hobby, and he's so good at his hobby that he's found a way to do it all the time.

On the other hand; you have a tennis star who is ultra-competitive. He loves tennis, but the part of it that he loves is competing (and beating when he can) the best in the sport. He craves holding that trophy aloft, in front of adoring fans. The money is just a means to the end of reaching that lofty height.

This man is a sportsman. Tennis is his chosen medium of competition and he works at it to be the best in his field.

Finally, we have a man who's very good at tennis, but it's not a passion. He's in it to win because that gives him a bigger paycheck that he can use on charitable work, buying a bigger house; whatever. His motivations for the money are immaterial.

This man is a performer. His job is to bring in crowds who pay to see him, and he'll adapt his playing style accordingly. He'll bring flair and attitude to the game so he attracts interest, which translate to appearance fees at smaller tournaments and the like. He'll have large contracts with companies like Armani, Longines, or similar long before others in the sport. He'll sport a fashionable or interesting haircut and will always be dressed in the most modern style possible.

Whether we like it or not, the business model for most sporting events around the world these days is 'put on an interesting show, get people to pay to watch it'. That makes those sporting events attractions in some form. There is an artistic side to this, and there are certainly some parallels with concerts or the theatre. Certainly, some 'sportsmen' are adapting by being more flashy rather than competitive, meaning that they bring their *own* audiences to events and therefore have higher bargaining power with the organisers.

But to be fair, not all sportsmen (I'm using these terms in a gender neutral context by the way) feel that way. Some love their sport, love competing against the best. To them, it's not about entertainment, it's about doing your best.

So, while ultimately the answer to your question is YES, that doesn't mean its the primary motivation for all people in that sport and it would be unfair to paint all sportsmen as performance artists or entertainers. As such, sport is what you get from it; it's just that in today's world, the major participation model is spectating.